# Using transactions for multiple functions in plsql

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a couple of stored procedures e.g newCallLog with a block like this:

```
procedure newCallLog(val_one in varchar2, val_two varchar2) is 
begin 
   if val_one = 'Good' then 
   -- insert into a table 
    else
    -- update a table 
    end if ;
end newCallLog ;

procedure newPhoneBill(val_one in varchar2, val_two varchar2) is 
begin 
   if val_one = 'Good' then 
   -- insert into a table 
    else
    -- update a table 
    end if ;
end newPhoneBill;
```

Now my question and concern is this , Is it proper to wrap these two functions within a transaction like this? , Any thoughts or suggestions are welcomed .

```
procedure saveCallLogs(val_one in varchar2, val_two varchar2) is 
 begin 

  newPhoneBill(val_one, val_two);
  newCallLog(val_one, val_two);
  commit ;
 WHEN  TIMEOUT_ON_RESOURCE THEN 
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20890,'The database server timed out , Please try again later ');
 WHEN  DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN 
 rollback;
 RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20880,'Some details already exists in the db currently . ');
 end saveCalllogs;
```

Comment: That's totally up to what the application business rules are that you define.  If the two functions are to be saved as one transaction, then yes. that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks that gave me a huge sigh of relief ,lol .

Comment: Also, if this saveCallLogs procedure is called as part of some larger process, it is usually best for the hosting application to determine if to do a commit or not.

Comment: It is actually called directly from the client application which is a vb.net app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this depends to your business. 
if the sub-process "newPhoneBill" is inseparable with "newCallLog" then you must keep both of these within one transaction. Only both are "atomic"

Example:

In an accounting system you have always two tasks to do:
1. Debit-Entry
2. Credit-Entry
A valid accounting entry consists always of these both sub-entries. This means a debit-entry cannot exists without a credit-entry and vice versa!